# Convert formatCurrency (rupiah) to int

Tags: java, string, integer

Here I have a method like this:

```
// method currency format
    private String formatRupiah(Double number) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("IND", "ID");
        NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        String formatRupiah = numberFormat.format(number);
        String[] split = formatRupiah.split(",");
        int length = split[0].length();
        String formatRupiahString = split[0].substring(0, 2) + " " + split[0].substring(2, length);
        return formatRupiahString;
    }
```

And also have this method to change the text that is in the edit text into the currency format:

```
private void editTextToFormatCurrency() {
        etJumlah.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            private String jumlahFormat = Objects.requireNonNull(etJumlah.getText()).toString().trim();

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (!s.toString().equals(jumlahFormat)) {
                    etJumlah.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String replace = s.toString().replaceAll("[Rp. ]", "");
                    if (!replace.isEmpty()) {
                        jumlahFormat = formatRupiah(Double.parseDouble(replace));
                    } else {
                        jumlahFormat = "";
                    }
                    etJumlah.setText(jumlahFormat);
                    etJumlah.setSelection(jumlahFormat.length());
                    etJumlah.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

And now my question is how to change TextToFormatCurrencycto int or Integer without format currency ? 
My goal of changing back to Integer or int is so I can upload to Firestore with data type number.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdgQW8T-KeQ&t (this is my video) 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NQOK2cam3js&t (this is my inspiration video)

```
String jumlahString = Objects.requireNonNull(String.valueOf(layoutJumlah.getEditText().getText()));
jumlahString = jumlahString.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
jumlah = Integer.parseInt(jumlahString);
```

Comment: Please don't mis-use answers to advertise your videos; instead write the answer in words. You *might* refer to a video for further information, but don't use it a a primary answer.